# Document Information Panel (DIP) fields variations not applied

Tags: 2013, content-type, office-integration, dip

I've a Document Content Type with multilingual fields set, however when document is open on MS Office (2010) the fields on the DIP are shown in the site default language. It's that a SP limitation or I'm missing something?

SPRegards

Update: Infopath not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIP is **always shown on the site collection default language** and does not support MUI. 
This seems to be a a SP 'limitation', maybe only overcome with Infopath.